# Simple node.js chat server issues

Tags: html, node.js, chat, server

Im having issues with a node.js server and HTML client.

The server code is:

```
var http = require('http');
    fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    }); 
}).listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)    {
    socket.on('message_to_server', function(data)   {
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",{ message: data["message"]});
    });
});
console.log('Server running')
```

And client code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rumors and speculations</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socketio = io.connect("localhost", {port: 1337});

        socketio.on("message_to_client", function (data) {
            document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML = ("<hr/>" +
            data['message'] + document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML);
        });
        function sendMessage() {
            var msg = document.getElementById("message_input").value;
            socketio.emit("message_to_server", { message: msg });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="message_input" />
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">send</button>
    <div id="chatlog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but i am running my HTML from Visual Studio (building an ASP.NET MVC app).

I get the chat button and windows for typing on the screen, but when i add some text and click 'send' nothing happens, and nothing is displayed.
Am I missing something? I would almost bet that I am missing something in regards to the server adress, but I have stared myself blind to be able to find it.

Comment: What socket.io version do you use?

Comment: I just installed it 30 mins. ago, so im guessing the newest.

Answer (score 1):

In your client code: 
data['message'] + document.getElementById("chatlog").**innterHTML** is spelled incorrectly. It should say **.innerHTML**

Comment: Oh thats true! However it didnt fix my problem unfortunately.

Comment: does it run the sendMessage function at all on click? Try adding an alert('#something') or a console.debug('#something')

Comment: I edited the code to this:
    <button onclick="sendMessage(); alert('You are clicking on me')">send</button>

And the alert doesn't pop up.